# Press key to turn on and press the same key to turn off

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created this script for showing a panel when I press the f1 key on my keyboard, and when I press f1 again the panel closes. This works, but if I keep my finger on the key the panel will show and hide continously. |

I want to press f1 once to show, and then press f1 again to hide the panel, without opening and closing the panel while the key is pressed.
Here the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HelpPanelScript : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject panel; // drop the panel in the editor
bool hide = false;
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F1))
    {
        hide = !hide;
        if (hide)
        {
            panel.SetActive(false);
        }
        else panel.SetActive(true);
    }
}
public void Start()
{
    panel.SetActive(false);
}
public void onAdvancedClicked()
{
    panel.SetActive(!panel.activeSelf); // make it active/inactive with one click
}
}
```

Comment: `GetKeyDown` or `GetKeyUp` may help instead of using just `GetKey`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Input.GetKey(<KeyCode>)` will check if that key is pressed and held *every frame*, as explained in [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) (emphasis mine):

> Returns true **while** the user holds down the key identified by name.

What you are looking for is `Input.GetKeyDown(<KeyCode>)` which will only fire off once on the frame the key is pressed down on, and will not be able to fire again until the key has been released (which can also be captured using `Input.GetKeyUp(<KeyCode>)`)

From the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) (emphasis mine):

> Returns true **during the frame the user starts pressing down the key** identified by name.

Therefore your script would need to look like this to get your desired behaviour:

```cs
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F1)) //Notice the usage of Input.GetKeyDown here
    {
        hide = !hide;
        if (hide)
        {
            panel.SetActive(false);
        }
        else panel.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MicheleLoizzo If this answer helped you solve your problem please accept it by clicking the little checkmark on the left side of the answer